Radio button not staying checked when I click another components
I wrote the code HTML like this:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<input class="add_task_radio" type="radio" name="prior" id="prior-2" value="2">
<label class="add_task_radio_icon" name="prior" for="prior-2" tabindex="1">
<i class="bi bi-check-circle text-light yellow"></i>
<i class="bi bi-circle text-light yellow"></i>
</label>
<input class="add_task_radio" type="radio" name="prior" id="prior-2" value="2">
<label class="add_task_radio_icon" name="prior" for="prior-2" tabindex="1">
<i class="bi bi-check-circle text-light yellow"></i>
<i class="bi bi-circle text-light yellow"></i>
</label>
<input type="text" name="task_name" placeholder="Name">

And CSS like this:
.add_task_radio {
    position:relative;
    display: none;
}
.button_space .bi-check-circle,.add_task_container .bi-check-circle,.add_task_radio_icon .bi-check-circle {
    display:none;
}
.button_space:hover .bi-check-circle,
.add_task_radio_icon:hover .bi-check-circle,
.add_task_radio_icon:active .bi-check-circle,
.add_task_radio_icon:checked .bi-check-circle,
.add_task_radio_icon:focus .bi-check-circle {
    display:inline;
}
.button_space:hover .bi-circle,
.add_task_radio_icon:hover .bi-circle,
.add_task_radio_icon:active .bi-circle,
.add_task_radio_icon:checked .bi-circle,
.add_task_radio_icon:focus .bi-circle {
    display:none;
}

Changing radio labels works fine. The problem is that the checked radio label is unchecked when I try to fill input name or click somewhere else. How to handle this?

CSS selectors not correctly targeting the checked state of the radio button. The :checked pseudo-class only applies directly to the input, not to the label.
To fix this, you need to style the label based on the state of the corresponding radio input:


.add_task_radio {
    display: none;
}

/* Default state: bi-check-circle is hidden, bi-circle is visible */
.add_task_radio_icon .bi-check-circle {
    display: none;
}
.add_task_radio_icon .bi-circle {
    display: inline;
}

/* When the radio button is checked, show the check-circle */
.add_task_radio:checked + .add_task_radio_icon .bi-check-circle {
    display: inline;
}

.add_task_radio:checked + .add_task_radio_icon .bi-circle {
    display: none;
}
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="add_task_container">
    <input class="add_task_radio" type="radio" name="prior" id="prior-1" value="1">
    <label class="add_task_radio_icon" for="prior-1" tabindex="1">
        <i class="bi bi-check-circle text-light yellow"></i>
        <i class="bi bi-circle text-light yellow"></i>
    </label>
    
    <input class="add_task_radio" type="radio" name="prior" id="prior-2" value="2">
    <label class="add_task_radio_icon" for="prior-2" tabindex="1">
        <i class="bi bi-check-circle text-light yellow"></i>
        <i class="bi bi-circle text-light yellow"></i>
    </label>
    
    <input type="text" name="task_name" placeholder="Name">
</div>
</body>
</html>



